# Stopping CSS3 KeyFrames Animation

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

i have animated a div as

```
div{
   animation-name:moveit;
  animation-duration:2s;
}

@keyframes moveit{
    0%{
     top:0;
   }
   100%{
     top:400px;
   }
}
```

This animation moves a div from `top 0px` to `top=400px` in `2sec`.

Now the problem is when animation ends it goes back to `top=0`... I want that when animation ends it should remain on `top=400px`;

It doesnot repeat but comes back to its original position but i want it to stay at 100%

Answer (score 0):

To persist the end state of the animation you can give your div element an initial top property.

```
div {
  top: 400px;
  animation-name: moveit;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

@keyframes moveit {
  0% { top: 0px; }
  100% { top: 400px; }
}
```

When the animation concludes the top property for your div will take over and you should have your desired effect.